# Explorer automatically opens new window

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, automation, window, user

I just did a fresh install of Win7 and was having a few issues getting it to know that I wanted the %userprofile% to be E:. Now I finally have that fixed, but for some reason explorer opens all new links and stuff in a new window. I checked and it says under options that it should open in the same window, but for some reason, it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two settings affect opening in a new window

A. Explorer/Tools/Folder Options/General/Open each folder in a new window.

B. Explorer/Tools/Folder Options/View/Launch folder windows in a separate process.